# Newbie in Python [2.7] function not working

Tags: python

I am using a script i've downloaded from the web to access our service API. 
I am trying to run the function, but keep getting errors no matter what I am trying to do.

```
from PyBambooHR import PyBambooHR

bamboo = PyBambooHR(subdomain='domain', api_key='apicode')
changes = bamboo.get_employee_changes()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error: since argument must be a datetime.datetime instance

Now, no matter what I set as arguments, I still getting errors. I've also tried the syntax from: https://www.bamboohr.com/api/documentation/changes.php

The function is:

```
def get_employee_changes(self, since=None):
    """
    Returns a list of dictionaries, each with id, action, and lastChanged keys, representing
    the employee records that have changed since the datetime object passed in the since= argument.

    @return List of dictionaries, each with id, action, and lastChanged keys.
    """
    if not isinstance(since, datetime.datetime):
        raise ValueError("Error: since argument must be a datetime.datetime instance")

    url = self.base_url + 'employees/changed/'
    params = {'since': since.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=self.headers, auth=(self.api_key, ''))
    r.raise_for_status()

    return utils.transform_change_list(r.content)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Apparently, although the parameter seems to have a default value, you **cannot** simply call `bamboo.get_employee_changes()`; you need to provide a date time `since` which you want to see changes. It's not clear why the maintainers provided that useless default.

Comment: I can't understand why someone would define a function with a default value and then raise an exception if the default value is used, nor why they chose to check for an exceptional case and then raise an exception rather than just try the task and let it raise its own exception.

Comment: That is such a strange default argument.

Comment: To be fair to the author, the custom exception has a very clear error message. I'm not sure why the OP didn't try passing a `datetime.datetime` instance.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in that function is a parameter *since* of type *datetime.datetime* expected.

```
import datetime
changes = bamboo.get_employee_changes(since=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365))
```

Should give you the changes since last year

Comment: Thank you, Matthias. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable of type `datetime.datetime` while calling the function `bamboo.get_employee_changes()`